# How can I return to my Main Menu after running through method and retrieve the 'return'? Having trouble understanding 'getter'

Tags: java

**What I have now:** I currently have a public class "MainMenu" where I greet the user and request them to enter in a set of numbers (1-10) for options they'd like to execute. This is picked up by a Switch case.

Inside each case will either run a small execution, or point towards a separate class.

**For example:**

```
    public static void mainMenu(Scanner sc) {
    //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Flight Scheduler!\n");
    System.out.println("Please remember to always use U, M, T, W, R, F, S, for entering");
    System.out.println("the day of the week, and to always use military time");
    System.out.println("for entering the time.");
    System.out.println("Please make your choice\nby entering the corresponding menu number:\n");

    System.out.println("1.\tSet Clock");
    System.out.println("2.\tClear Schedule");
    System.out.println("3.\tAdd Airline");
    System.out.println("4.\tAdd Flight");
    System.out.println("5.\tCancel Flight");
    System.out.println("6.\tShow Flight Info");
    System.out.println("7.\tShow Departures");
    System.out.println("8.\tShow Arrivals");
    System.out.println("9.\tFind Flights Between Two Airports");
    System.out.println("10.\tExit\n");

    int userChoice = sc.nextInt();

    switch (userChoice) {
      case 1:
      AirlineAircraftData.AddAirline(sc);
      break;
```

This executes my *AddAirline* method, which I'd like to return an object back to the main menu, and allow the user to continue to choose from the 10 options provided earlier, right after having entered the fields requested from the *AddAirline* method.

**Here is the method I'm running through after the user selects it:**

```
    public static A8AirlineAircraftData AddAirline(Scanner sc) {
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Airline name:");
    String airName = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the Airline code:");
    String airCode = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Delta Aircraft:");
    String airCraft = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the first class seat capacity:");
    int firstClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the business class seat capacity:");
    int busiClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the economy class seat capacity:");
    int econClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Airline name: " + airName);
    System.out.println("Airline code: " + airCode);
    System.out.println("Delta Aircraft: " + airCraft);
    //Splitting the first word from the rest of the string
    String arr[] = airCraft.split(" ", 2);
    String firstWord = arr[0];
    System.out.println(firstWord + " first class seat capacity: " + firstClass);
    System.out.println(firstWord + " business class seat capacity: " + busiClass);
    System.out.println(firstWord + " economy class seat capacity: " + econClass);
    //Airline object
    A8AirlineAircraftData airline = new A8AirlineAircraftData(airName, airCode, airCraft, firstClass, busiClass, econClass);
    System.out.println(airName + " successfully added. Press Enter to continue.");
    sc.nextLine();//Press Enter to continue
    sc.nextLine();   
    //A8MainMenu.mainMenu(sc); //return to main menu after Enter. 
    return airline;
```

Thank you for any help, I'm a rookie and I know a lot of what I'm doing doesn't necessarily make sense.

Comment: Normally you'd run the main menu in a loop, and exit the loop when the user selects Exit.

Comment: I was told running the *A8MainMenu.mainMenu(sc);* line wouldn't be acceptable. Why is this the case?

Comment: It's not good practice because it puts more things on the stack.  If you did that, and the user went through the menu enough times, eventually you'd get a `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of @D M, I was able to figure out how to fix this. I just wrapped the entire main menu in a do-while loop that exits on '10'.